# Empty microphone data from getUserMedia

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api, getusermedia

Using the following code I get all zeroes in the audio stream from my microphone (using Chrome):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(
   function(stream) {
      var audioContext = new AudioContext();
      var source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      var node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(8192, 1, 1);
      source.connect(node);
      node.connect(audioContext.destination);
      node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
         console.log("Audio:", e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0));
      };  
  }).catch(function(error) {console.error(error);})
```

I created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/g3dck4dr/

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Umm, something in your hardware config is wrong?  The fiddle works fine for me (that is, it shows non-zero values).  Do other web audio input tests work, like https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/input/index.html?

Test to make sure you've selected the right input, and you don't have a hardware mute switch on.